# Excel: Dynamic Ranges with periodically skipped cells (to create Dynamic Charts)

Tags: excel, dynamic, graph, range, offset

I struggle with Excel in order to generate a water consumption monitoring each month.

Objective: Create a graph in which data are automatically added each month.

Issue: My table is not so common. I want a specific disposition. I have a yearly set up (see screenshot):

- first line: Year (Y): yearly stats (sum)
- Jan (Y)
- Feb (Y)
- each month of the year (Y).
- 14th line: Year (Y+1) (next year's stats)
- 15th: Jan(Y+1)

With that special table, I wonder if there is any way to define dynamic range with every month AND SKIP the Yearly stats line. 
I want a continuous graph with months of every years...

I know some function such as "OFFSET" exists to do so in Excel but I struggle with it to automatically skip one line on 13.

I hope my English isn't so bad and that I was quite clear enough to get your precious help!

Thank you in advance!

**Screenshots**

The table has yearly row to skip while selecting monthly data to put in the graph

[image: First]

You can see here what I want to get as a result: graph with every month automatically added.

[image: Second]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your English is just fine. There may be a better solution, but if your data are now fixed and not being added anymore, why wouldn't you just use another (possibly hidden) column that would be the source for data of your chart?

You could create that column for instance in two steps. First, create a column with the addresses of the data you want to have in your chart in that order.

For instance, if your data would be in cells `C1,C2,...` and you would like to skip one row after each 12 rows, you could create column `E` like this:

```
=CONCAT("C",ROW()+QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,12))
```

(put this same formula into all rows of `E`, just copy&paste)

This creates the names of the cells in column `E` in a consecutive manner:
`C1, C2, ..., C12, C14, C15, ..., C25, C27, ...`

Then in another column, for instance `G`, enter the following formula to the first row and then copy it to all other rows of `G`:

```
=INDIRECT(E1)
```

(while copying, it will automatically refer to `E2`, `E3`, etc.)

Now your column `G` contains continuous data from column `C`, skipping one row after every next 12 rows, and you can use it to create your chart.

And yet another solution using only one extra column (same idea, but more simple), use the INDEX() function. Create a column E containing the following formula in all rows:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$35,ROW()+QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,12))
```

It will do the same - retrieve the contents of C1 into E1, C2 int E2, etc. C12 into E12, C14 into E13, etc.

And in your particular case, when the data start in C4, instead of C1, you would use:

```
=INDEX($C$4:$C$35,ROW()-3+QUOTIENT(ROW()-4,12))
```

If you also like to have your chart automatically updated each time you add a value, one way to do it is like this. You can define a dynamic range:

In the "Formulas" menu select "Name Manager", click "New..." and give it some name, such as "chartrange", and into the Refers to: row enter this formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$E$5,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$E$5:$E$1000),1)
```

This will define a dynamic range from E5 until there are some non-blank values in that column. And then click on your chart with right mouse - Select data... click the Edit... button on the left, and enter the name "chartrange" into the Series values: line.

I have posted an example here: [chart with dynamically added data](http://kempelen.dai.fmph.uniba.sk/dynamic_chart.xlsx)

See also:

- [How to Create a Dynamic Chart Range in Excel](https://trumpexcel.com/dynamic-chart-range/)
- [Can I hide columns without excluding the data from a graph?](https://superuser.com/questions/207845/excel-2010-can-i-hide-columns-without-excluding-the-data-from-a-graph)

Comment: Hi Palo, thank you very much. 

Your idea works and allows me to go further with my problem. One last thing would be to be able to automate these manipulations when I add data every month. Is there a way to ask Excel to automatically add a new reference (C14, C15, ...) then a new call to the indirect function and finally that the graph is automatically filled when I add a new data in my C column? 

Or maybe should I just define a range name for my "Indirect-column (G)" then define my graph with?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the answer to include explanation on dynamically updated chart and a link to an example. If you like the answer, you can accept it. ;)

Comment: Okay just found it. Thank you very much Palo, my sheet is ready and thanks to you I was able to get what I wanted!

Comment: I am glad it was useful for you, this is what SO is for. I will need to do some programming work in Excel soon, so I thought I need some refresh, so it was useful for me at least. At SO when you are satisfied with some answer to a question you post, please click on the checkmark/tick symbol on the left to the answer to make it green - it will give me reputation points and motivate me to answer another question like yours another time. I have marked your question with the up arrow, to indicate that it was useful to me, and that increases your reputation. Take care and good luck!